# Draw string value text modal

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

so I was trying to draw a text and a string value, more specifically, the value of the width of the bevel modifier. I achieved it but the string value seems to long, I want it to be shorter let's say I want only 0.0310 to display in the text without the extra numerals. How do i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you must use the `round` function...

in line 14 add something like this:

```
bevelWV = round(bevelWV, 4)
```